# Multiple values in cakephp session

Tags: cakephp

I would like to store multiple values in cakephp session where some value come through database and some from manually

I have created a session in controller which is like this.

```
 $this->Session->write('Cart.'.$count,$this->Product->findById($id[0], array('id','category','name','price'))); //controller
```

And I have wrote this code in view page

```
 foreach( $this -> Session -> read(Cart) as $value)
 {
      echo $value['Product']['id'];
      echo $value['Product']['category'];
      echo $value['Product']['name'];
      echo $value['Product']['price'];
 }
```

by using this line i can print all information id,category,name,price which is stored from database in session

but i want to add one more variable which is $quantity and it will manually not coming from database so how can i add this field in session and how can i print this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write session do somthing like given below:

```
  $sessionInfo = $this->Product->findById($id[0], array('id','category','name','price'));
  foreach($sessionInfo as $key=>$value){
    $sessionInfo[$key]['Product']['quantity'] = $count;
  }
  $this->Session->write('Cart',$sessionInfo); //controller
```

View session data:

```
foreach( $this->Session->read('Cart') as $value)
     {
          echo $value['Product']['id'];
          echo $value['Product']['category'];
          echo $value['Product']['name'];
          echo $value['Product']['price'];
          echo $value['Product']['quantity'];
     }
```

Comment: set values of session in controller as $userInfo = $this->Session->read('Cart'); and then in view file foreach($userInfo as $value){}

Comment: now it giving two errors Notice (8): Undefined variable: userInfo [APP\View\products\addcart.ctp, line 4]
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP\View\products\addcart.ctp, line 4]

Comment: Ok...So now you have to debug $userInfo = $this->Session->read('Cart'); see what is the output of this and also update your question with controller code.

Comment: after debug its output like this array(
 'Product' => array(
  'id' => '4',
  'category' => 'Ring',
  'name' => 'ronak',
  'price' => '84',
  'Product' => array(
   'quantity' => (int) 1
  )
 )
)

Comment: thanks alot now its working perfect i was doing some mistakes thanks :)